# Is any possible way to get warning message through by oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I am working in developing oracle data base tool and I want display a warning message when executing a function, for example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_OEDS_CONVERTDATE2(
V_DATE DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    V_RETVALUE VARCHAR2(15) :='';
    BEGIN


    SELECT
        CASE V_DATE
            WHEN NULL THEN ''
            ELSE TO_CHAR(V_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        END INTO V_RETVALUE FROM DUAL

     RETURN V_RETVALUE;
    END;

END;
/
```

The above function will execute successfully, but it won't throw any error message even though its status would be invalid.

How would I get the warning message thrown out in Java?

Comment: What kind of error do you mean?

Comment: Function status is invalid means there must be some issue. your code must populate `SQLException` with info.

Comment: In java i could able to get warning by st.getWarnings() , but display in general java.sql.SQLWarning: Warning: execution completed with warning , can i able to query and get exact oracle .

Comment: To be honest. If you just add the semi-colon after `dual` then this'll compile fine. Why not just ensure that everything is coded correctly and test that this is so?

Comment: Yes i am working with SQLException

Answer (score 2):

Compiler messages are not returned to the client through the getWarnings() on the statement or the connection.

Instead once you have identified the warning through `Statement.getWarnings()` you need to parse retrieve the compiler errors from the view `ALL_ERRORS`

Something like:

```
SELECT line, 
       position, 
       text, 
       name, 
       type 
FROM all_errors 
WHERE owner = user
AND type = 'FUNCTION'
AND name = 'FN_OEDS_CONVERTDATE2'
ORDER BY line, position
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if the object is invalid "before" running it ? Something like this will help.

```
select *
from 
   dba_objects 
where 
   status != 'VALID'
order by
   owner,
   object_type
;
```

Comment: It's [_never_ wise to write `select *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select).

Comment: @Ben: of course, but that was just an example. if you look at the where condition you'll clearly see it doesn't filter on obj name.